# ER diagram situation where there are many unknown roles but one specific one is different

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

Lets say I have have employees and they all have basic stuff like name and phone number but they also have one or more roles however for one specific role, say salesperson (and no others) a little extra information needs to be stored. I also don't know and can never know all possible roles and new roles could be made at any time.

What is the best way to represent this on an ER diagram? If it wasn't for the salesperson I would just use a multi-valued attribute.

The best ways I can think of are:
Overlapping subclasses with 'salesperson' and 'other' as the possibilities. However I don't really think this is a good solution because I have never seen 'other' on an ER diagram before.

I could have a single non total participation subclass for the salesperson that can store the extra information but then otherwise have a multivalued attribute on the employee entity that represents all roles? Still doesn't seem good to me because there is redundancy and information not stored together.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two tables, Employee and Salesperson.

Employee includes all data you capture for all kinds of employees, including salespersons.  The key is Employee.Id

Salesperson only has entries for salespersons.  It contains specialized data for salesperson.  The key is Salesperson.EmployeeId.  This is also a foreign key, referencing Employee.Id.

When you want all the data about sales persons, just join the two tables together, using the keys.  You could have a view that makes this join available.

This is an adaptation of class-table-inheritance and shared-primary-key.